# How to parse widget in json format in magento 2.4.4?

Tags: magento2.4

Is it possible to parse widget code to JSON format?

```
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" template="Magento_CatalogWidget::product/widget/content/grid.phtml" anchor_text="" id_path="" show_pager="0" products_count="5" condition_option="category_ids" condition_option_value="675" type_name="Catalog Products List" conditions_encoded="^[1:^[aggregator:all,new_child:``,type:Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine,value:1^],1--1:^[operator:==,type:Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Product,attribute:category_ids,value:675^]^]" sort_order="position"}}
```

Any way to convert? Please help me on this